# How to convert chanakya text into hindi text string using java

Tags: java, text, unicode

I want to convert Chanakya text -  °ÙÁèü SÅUôÚUðÁ §´çÇUØæ (§ü°â¥æ§ü) w®v} 

into hindi  एनर्जी स्टोरेज इंडिया (ईएसआई) 2018  using java.

I have so many file to convert and  want to automate the process using java. Is there any library which can help me do it.

There are my online converter but there is no information how they convert or how we can achieve the same using java.

Comment: Guys please let me know the reason to down vote the question so that i can ask right question (Or in right format ) in future.

Comment: try https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java . for supported languages, you need to check docs

Comment: @akshayapandey thanks for your reply. I will try the given solution. Thanks